# Looking for a way to return all nested associations using deep_clonable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested association where I have Rubric > Indicator > Question. In this gist you can see I step through the association correctly, then try to to clone the object and its associations. However, notice I have an empty array for klone.questions. I can do `klone.indicators.first.questions` and retrieve all questions associated with the first indicator, but I am looking for a way to retrieve all questions associated with a rubric (klone in this case).

https://gist.github.com/1389697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its looks like deep_clonable cannot handle has_many :through type associations. I ended up doing this by hand like this:

```
  def create
template = Template.find params[:template][:id]
params[:section_ids].each do |section|
  @rubric = Rubric.new(template.attributes.merge(:name => template.name))
  @rubric.section_id = section
  @rubric.save
  template.indicator_templates.each do |i|
    indicator = Indicator.new(:name => i.name, :rubric_id => @rubric.id)
    indicator.save
    i.question_templates.each do |q|
      question = Question.new(:name => q.name, :indicator_id => indicator.id)
      question.save
    end
  end
end
if @rubric.save
  redirect_to rubrics_path, :notice => "Successfully created rubric."
else
  render :action => 'new'
end
end
```

So for the 3 models I am trying to clone (Rubrics, Indicators and Questions) I created 3 other models that basically mimic these models. I called them Template (for Rubric), IndicatorTemplate(for Indicators) and QuestionTemplate(for Questions). Then I create a new Rubric, and step through the indicators and questions making the proper associations along the way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using `has_many :questions, :through => :indicators`. Is there a chance this is not compatible with the deep clone in the way you're using it? What do you get with `klone.indicators.first.questions`?

Comment: Yes, I am using `has_many :questions, :through => :indicators`. When I do `klone.indicators.first.questions` I do get all questions associated with the first indicator. I edited the question to reflect this.